# Contingency planner question

Tags: pandemic

If it's my turn and I am the contingency planner, can I use a special event card then use an action to put the card on contingency planner then use that event again in the same turn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assuming the Contingency Planner isn't already "storing" a different event, that is perfectly within the rules and the text of the Contingency Planner.

During your turn, you (or any other player) can play an event card from hand, and that event goes to the discard pile.

You can then use the CP's ability to spend an action to pick up that event and store it on his card.

The stored card can be played at any time, as normal (but is then removed from the game rather than being discarded).